# How to use MS access on a server where MS Office is not installed

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

i want to run macros and queries on ms access database but my server doesn't have ms office installed so i am not able to use Interop classes.How to fetch data from ms access on a server where ms office is not installed ?

Comment: Do you develop an ASP.NET web application?

Comment: No , we connect to access db and run some macro/queries using vba code currently on severs. But ms office is going to get uninstalled from servers. so how to run macros without creating instance of access application ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe install Access Runtime on the server? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040